# Flux of vector field. Gauss' Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, divergence-operator

Let´s try to solve the following exercise :

*Calculate the flux of the vector field: **f**$(x,y,z) = (x^2,y^2,z^2)$ through the surface $S = \{x^2+y^2=z^2,0\leq\ z \leq\ 1\} $ (orientation fixed).*

***My attempt***

I tried to solve it using Gauss' Theorem. The closed surface of the volume would be $ S $ $ \cup$ $S_1 $ where $S_1 $ is the surface that describes the circle $ x^2 +y^2 =1 $ in the plane $ z=1$. We are interested in calculating the integral:

$ \iint_S $ **f** $\cdot\ $**n** $dS = \iiint_V div $ **f** $dxdydz -  \iint_{S_1} $ **f** $\cdot\ $**n** $dS_1 $

In my case:

$div$ **f** $ =2x+2y+2z $

To calculate the first integral, I decided to use cylindrical coordinates:

$x=\rho \cos\varphi$

$y = \rho \sin \varphi$

$z = z$

Using that $x^2+y^2=z^2 $ on the cone, we have that $\rho = z$. The limits of integration could be:

$ 0\leq\ \rho \leq\ 1\ $

$ 0\leq\ \varphi \leq\ 2\pi $

$ \rho\leq\ z \leq\ 1 $

Putting it all together:

$ \iiint_V div$ **f** $dxdydz = 2 \cdot \int _{0}^{1} \int _{0}^{2\pi} \int _{\rho}^{1} (\rho (\cos \varphi + \sin \varphi) +z) \cdot \rho \cdot d \rho d\varphi dz $

For the second integral, we parametrize the surface: $r_1(x,y) = (x,y,1)$

$ \iint_{S_1} $ **f** $\cdot\ $**n** $dS_1 = \iint_Q (x^2,y^2,1) \cdot (0,0,1) dxdy = \mu (Q) = \pi $

where $Q = \{(x,y) \in R^2|x^2+y^2 \leq\ 1\} $

My questions are:

Is it correct? What can we say about the orientation? Is there a simpler way?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You can only apply Gauss's Theorem on a closed surface. $S$ isn't a closed surface, but you can close it by "putting on the lid" $$T=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2\leq 1, z=1\}$$ The triple integral you wrote actually calculates the outward flux through $T\cup S$.

Comment: Very true! I have modified my approach.